# Is there any romantic angle suggested between Po and Tigeress?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

I am a big fan of the Kung Fu Panda movies and I just finished watching the second part. I noticed that there are a lot of scenes where the director was hinting at some kind of special bond between Po and Tigress, especially the last scene where Po hugs Tigress and all the others watch in awe. So I wanted to ask, is there any romantic angle being suggested between Po & Tigress ?

Comment: I think it's more to do with Tigress' acceptance of Po, considering she was the one who took the longest to warm to him in the first film.

Comment: Probably just Jack Black trying to cop a feel from Angelina Jolie

Comment: I didn't think so ... I was looking at it more like a bother/sister relationship. I think Tigress feels responsible for Po because he is a "sibling".

Comment: I honestly think these two show a little more than a brother-sister relationship. They seem to really be fond of each other if they are willing to risk their lives for each other. Plus, I wouldn't be surprised if Dreamworks decided to put them together. It's a kids film. ANYTHING can happen!!!! May I remind you all of Donkey and Dragon from Shrek? Yeah. That definitely happened. Or a blue alien ending up with a human news reporter in Megamind? Yeah. That happened. And what about Gloria the hippo and Melman the giraffe in Madagascar? That happened too. So, putting together a panda and a tiger i

Comment: You seem to have run out of characters there @user6948

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even in the 1st movie, they hinted to this relationship through a couple of points in the movie. here are the hints that I noticed.

1. In the beginning Po wakes up and is commenting on his action figures of the furious five especially tigress who he tries to imitate her roar. This shows that he admires her as a Kung Fu master although secretly after watching this, he does, in fact, have a small crush on her.
2. When Po goes to the training hall for the first time, he immediately is watching Tigress and ends up getting hit in the face when she breaks the swinging club thingy. Some may argue that it was just a coincidence, but while watching the movie look at Po's face right before he gets hit he has the look of "holy crap, she looks beautiful."
3. At the end of the movie, Tigress is the first of all the five to bow to Po and call him master, and then she smiles at him. This might have shocked Po but he was finally accepted in his mind.

Also watching the Kung Fu panda legends of awesomeness. Why this relationship needs to happen. There are a couple of reasons in these shows, I'll list them.

1. Tigress makes a comment after one of her comrades broke up with their girlfriend, saying that she avoids relationships because of the disruption of one's chi. I would like to point out the word avoids this is not the same as stay away from or never going to happen, so to me, this is another hint.
2. In a couple of other episodes both Po and tigress interact quite a lot in a lot of different ways. Tigress also doesn't hate Po, she just finds him pestering.
3. Both Po and Tigress have similar backgrounds. Both were orphans and both were taken in by someone, Po by Mr. Ping and Tigress by Master Shifu. Had they been raised by the other dad, they would have turned out differently.

Lastly, in the 2nd movie, there are way more of these hints and foreshadowing events that cause people to speculate that this relationship will happen. Here are the hints I found.

1. After the introduction, it shows two kids playing with a Po and Tigress action figure. At first, you might think "so what?," but when you factor in why didn't they have a crane or a viper action figure, then maybe you come to the conclusion that this is a hint, but this is more of a personal preference hint.
2. In the training hall, Po is trying to beat the 38 bean bun record, and typically, Tigress would find this stupid and disgusting, but she actually encourages him. also during the same scene Po hears a bell and has to go see Shifu and as he's leaving you notice tigress turn around watching him go and TADA she smiles in a fantasy kinda way, Ok first off she doesn't do that every day, okay?
3. When the five and po go to fight, po and tigress have tag team moves or as i would like to call it the tango because it looks a lot like they are dancing while doing kung fu. Also in the same scene she goes out of her way to try and save po from the boss wolfs hammer but fails.
4. The boat scene tigress really comes out of her shell to talk to po one on one and she was about to say something before getting cut off. I have this feeling whatever she was going to say was going to bring them much closer together.
5. Tigress appears to always be in pos general area in almost every scene and she apears to always watch his back.
6. In the jail she wants to know the truth to why po let shen go and when he didn't answer this angered her because she cares for him and she didn't want him to be killed. So that is why she told him to stay in the jail.
7. When po neglects tigress's commands she is worried for him and tries to get to him and fails as po is shot and she is shocked that it happened saying NOOOOO!!!!! as she tried to save him.
8. When the five are chained up and monkey points out that po would want them to remain hardcore to the end and tries to confirm this with tigress who is Crying over po being dead ok we are talking about tigress a Iron lady ok she really dosen't just cry for everyone.
9. When po comes back to save the five she is the first to notice him saying PO?
10. She pushes po out of the way of shens cannon blast not wanting po to be hit again. she just wont push anyone out of the way of a cannon blast and im sure of that.
11. Po swims over to tigress and holds her paw obviously showing that he cares for her as well and is angry at shen for hurting his friends and tigress.
12. after the final battle tigress pulls po out of the water commenting how that stunt was pretty hardcore. at this po huggs HER ok different from the jail because she expected the one in the jail not at the end though. She was shocked but obviousely not mad

Comment: While I think this is a brilliant answer I can't help but thinking that these are just hints left by the film makers.  I can't see a romance happening because of the nature of the film.  I believe they're hinting at things from a child's perspective - it's simply the "oooo they like each other" you'd get in the playground.

Comment: None of these bullet points confirm a crush or potential relationship. Specifically: 1. Tigress is the most promising and thus famous of the Five 2. Po is fanstruck over all five of them, not just Tigress. He's happy being attacked by one of his idols. 3. Tigress was the strongest to initially reject him, which is why her bow "confirms" that Po is not accepted. The others already tried to make Po feel accepted before then. 2. Tigress and Po are often at odds because their characters are polar opposites. She is stoic and reverent, Po is naive and excited. [..]

Comment: 1. As established, Tigress was already the most famous of the Five. Po is new and therefore also very popular. 2. Po's eating challenge, while a different discipline than kung fu, is all about pushing yourself to reach unseen heights. That is exactly how Tigress approaches Kung Fu, so she likes Po doing something similar here. 3. (and 7) Plenty of the members have tried to save each other over the course of the movies. 6. Po is doing the opposite of what a "good student" would do (as she sees it), which is why she is angered. 10. makes no sense - why would she not save her friends?

Comment: To summarize, Tigress **represents** the Five. She is the [face of the band](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FaceOfTheBand) (trope). This is why she interacts with Po more than the other Four. Not because of a romantic arc, but because of her role within the Five (i.e. mostly condensing all of the Five's interactions into one character for narrative simplicity) **and** the fact that her character is the most polar opposite to Po's, thus driving the social friction and character arcs. She cares for him as one of her friends, but not specifically romantically.

Comment: _Correction: 3. Tigress was the strongest to initially reject him, which is why her bow "confirms" that Po is **now** accepted._

Answer (score 1):

I think that Tigress cares for Po a lot more than she does for any other of her team, but you cannot deny that there's any romance there. In one episode (the way of the prawn) the prawn and Po fight and it seams as if the prawn didn't do anything but Po's pants fall down and every one looks shocked but Tigress. she just looks on.

Answer (score 1):

The production staff before have stated in various interviews that it is an angle they all like a lot and would like to make happen at some stage. Jolie as well has said she believes it is a good idea to do and she likes Po and Tigress being together, though Black had said around the second film that it wasn't happening.

While a romance between Po and Tigress certainly hasn't happened yet across any of the films, series or shorts that have been produced, it certainly has been hinted at being in fruition in many places, both subtly and not so. In my view, considering they've planned for doing 6 movies, I think that the interactions between the two and the retrospective changes in attitude from Tigress are certainly building up towards something. Whether or not that blooms into a romantic relationship is something that can only be observed at a later date.

For now, no romantic relation of any kind between them, but there are hints of something growing.